# Grid width not textwidth when using fillwithgrid (exam package)

Tags: indentation, exam, grids

When inserting space for answers by `\fillwithdottedlines` the resulting lines have the same width as textwidth. When using `\fillwithgrid` the resulting grid is smaller on both sides:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}     

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[4] Warum gibt es Luft?

\lipsum[1]

\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

\bigskip

\fillwithgrid{2cm}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

How to get the exact same width?

The solution in an older post was to change `\textwidth`. But this only extends the grid on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a combination of problems. First `\fillwithgrid` only draws complete squares with a specific size (5 mm per default), this makes it very unlikely that the resulting grid will be exactly the same width as `\linewidth` (`\textwidth` does not take into account that the line is shorter due to the enumeration of the question)

I thought that using a fraction of the `\linewidth` as size of the squares should avoid this problem, e.g.

```
\setlength{\gridsize}{\dimexpr.1\linewidth-11\gridlinewidth}   
\fillwithgrid{2cm}
```

but for reasons unknown to me, this draws only 9 squares instead of the 10 ones I was expecting....

**Resorting to the heavy `tikz` weapons instead**

```
\documentclass[addpoints,a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[4] Warum gibt es Luft?

\lipsum[1]

\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

\bigskip


\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[step=0.5,black,thin] (0,0) grid (\linewidth,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this approach als calculating the size of the squares as a fraction of the `\linewidth` works:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[4] Warum gibt es Luft?

\lipsum[1]

\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[step=0.05\linewidth-0.01pt,black,thin] (0,0) grid (\linewidth,0.2\linewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}%


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The code of `exam.cls` uses `\leaders` for horizontal positioning, in a hbox taking up the full line width, and an initial whitespace of the total left margin, in a list environment. This feature of the class means that the grid squares will look vertically aligned independently of the actual left margin. But this left margin has no chance of being an exact multiple of the unit grid size, so the starting point of the squares looks a bit arbitrary and if you use a large value always systematically shifted the right because its absolute horizontal positioning must start at an integer multiple of gridsize from left border of text area.

In the code here I patch the `\list` to have a left margin of 2 gridsizes. And I adjust the gridsize so that an integer multiple fits in the whole width. This gives a modified gridsize of `5.13mm` in place of `5mm`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints,a4paper,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}     

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\questions{\settowidth{\leftmargin}{10.\hskip\labelsep}}
                   {\leftmargin=2\gridsize}
                   {\typeout{PATCH SUCCEEDED}}
                   {\PATCHFAILED}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\count@ \dimexpr\textwidth-\gridlinewidth\relax
\divide\count@ by \numexpr\dimexpr5mm\relax\relax
\gridsize\dimexpr(\textwidth-\gridlinewidth)/\count@\relax

\typeout{WE MODIFIED \string\gridsize\space TO \the\gridsize, i.e.
         \the\numexpr\gridsize*15875/29601792 mm/100
         SO WHEN USED INSIDE QUESTION THERE ARE \the\numexpr\count@-2\relax
         \space SQUARES IN HORIZONTAL LINES}
\makeatother

\begin{questions}
\question[4] Warum gibt es Luft?

blah blah blah (\number\gridsize)

\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

\bigskip
\noindent X\dotfill X\par

\bigskip

\fillwithgrid{2cm}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
WE MODIFIED \gridsize TO 14.60864pt, i.e. 513mm/100 SO WHEN USED INSIDE QUESTION THERE ARE 29 SQUARES IN HORIZONTAL LINES
```

Comment: maybe real life will need `3\gridsize` not `2\gridsize` to accomodate question numbers with 2 digits.

Comment: an alternative is to rewrite `\fillwithgrid` to add an `\hbox` layer containing the leaders *after* the initial `\hskip\@totalleftmargin` so the square will be correctly aligned whathever the unit width with the indentation (left margin) defined by the environment. But of course then the unit width has also to be adjusted if the available space is to be filled completely.